# What's the problem with my stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have to test some features with store procedures in mysql, so i trying to create one in MySQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_test(IN in_id Varchar(20), IN in_name Varchar(20))
BEGIN
    insert into test(id, name) values(in_id, in_name);
END
```

but I have an error:

> Error executing INSERT statement. Unknown column 'in_id' in 'field list' - Connection: MySQLConnection: 16ms

What's wrong with that? If i change in_d and in_name variables to static values like 'test1', 'test2' it works ok.

upd:
I tried with delimeters - no effect:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_test(IN in_id Varchar(10), IN in_name 
Varchar(30))
    BEGIN
        insert into test(id, name) values(in_id, in_name);
    END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Is this just to learn about procedures?

Comment: Is your ID column have number datatype in test table? That might be an issue.

Comment: I see no evidence that you are setting delimiters? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Comment: Id column has varchar type

Comment: Error message makes it seem like its the INSERT statement that is failing, not the CREATE PROCEDURE statement.  When did MySQL start supporting the `OR REPLACE` syntax on the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement? That must be the newest version of MySQL, because that's never worked before. (Is that error being reported when the CREATE PROCEDURE statement executes, or on a CALL to the stored procedure... some significant details are missing, I think the actual cause of  problem has been factored out in the abbreviated re-telling here.

Comment: Error message reported makes it seem like this is not from the MySQL command line client (which would typically report the error number and sqlstate) e.g. `ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'in_id' in 'field list'`, and we typically wouldn't see that specific error from the "create procedure" statement. We would get that error when we execute the procedure, using a `CALL`  statement.  Again, the retelling of this tale omits the most pertinent details...

Comment: Where are you running this and how - is it a local mysql server using workbench (for example)?

Comment: I got this to work just fine, check this out: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hhuaAF424a5JBMcTAYoPhu/0

Comment: This is NOT MySQL problem. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=ae0083ea9828ccc50adb7bb70698527c

Comment: Note that the provided, working db-fiddle demonstrations omit the problematic **`OR REPLACE`** syntax included in OP demonstration SQL.

Comment: just found this post, comment by dbdemon says `CREATE OR REPLACE` is supported via maria db : https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/126312/is-there-an-alternative-to-create-or-replace-procedure-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i have created my table and store procedure via DB Browser in Intellij Idea, m.b. therw was a problem. I just recreated table and procedure via mysql console.